# Ag-Grid rowSpan and autoHeight

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We've encouterred a problem where we need to use rowSpan and autoHeight (or any kind of dynamic height) for a cell in tandem.

According to the docs, autoHeigth is not supported when using rowSpan: https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/27.1.0/react-data-grid/row-spanning/#constraints-with-row-spanning

Our scenario:
We have a grid, where the first column is a "grouping" column, and the next columns are for "children" properties. E.g.: United States has 4 athletes, so the first column would span 4 rows, and the others 1. The issue is, we need to show more information in the first column, and it works ok if there are 2 or more "children" - the information fits in the cell, but when there is only 1 "child", the 1st column only spans 1 row and the information's does not fit. Some kind of mechanism is needed to make the row higher when, let's say rowSpan is less than 2.

`Here's the a simple plunker to represent the scenario:` https://plnkr.co/edit/lSO9tOKPfsBmrzPC

[As seen in the screenshot, the cell contents do not fit, on row 5 (2 based on the 1 column rowSpan)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vm9Q.png)

Since autoHeight is not supported when using rowSpan, has anyone encountered a similar scenario and has a suggestion for a workaround for dynamic height?